# Get the minimum variation price in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-variations

I am a beginner trying to learn Wordpress and have a variable product with prices:

- cod Rs 250
- online Rs 200

I want to use the minimum price in my themes `functions.php`.

How will I be able to fetch or get the minimum value?

I want to use in the below code :

```
function filter_gateways($gateways){

    $payment_NAME = 'cod'; // 
    $min_variation_price = ''; <--------------- minimum variation price

    global $woocommerce;

    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
        // Get the terms, i.e. category list using the ID of the product
        $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
        // Because a product can have multiple categories, we need to iterate through the list of the products category for a match
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            // 20 is the ID of the category for which we want to remove the payment gateway
            if($term->term_id == $min_variation_price){
                unset($gateways[$payment_NAME]);
                // If you want to remove another payment gateway, add it here i.e. unset($gateways['cod']);
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return $gateways;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the minimum variation active price in WooCommerce from a **`WC_Product_Variable`** object:

```
$variation_min_price = $product->get_variation_price();
```

> It seems that you are trying here to unset 'cod' payment gateway when a cart item min variation price is matching with his product category ID.

Using the WordPress conditional function **`has_term()`** will really simplify your code (it accepts term Ids, term slugs or term names for any taxonomy (as 'product_cat' here for product categories).

I suppose that your function is hooked in **`woocommerce_available_payment_gateways`** filter hook…

I made some changes in your code as it's a bit outdated and with some errors:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'conditional_payment_gateways', 10, 1);
function conditional_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    // Not in backend (admin)
    if( is_admin() ) 
        return $available_gateways;

    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        // Get the WC_Product object
        $product = wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']);
        // Only for variable products
        if($product->is_type('variable')){
            // Get the Variation "min" price
            $variation_min_price = $product->get_variation_price();
            // If the product category match with the variation 'min" price
            if( has_term( $variation_min_price, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ){
                // Cash on delivery (cod) payment gateway
                unset($available_gateways['cod']); // unset 'cod'
                break; // stop the loop
            }
        }
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This should work *(but I can't really test it as it's very specific regarding the product categories ID and the min variation prices)*…

---

#### All related price methods for variable product type:

```
// All prices: multidimensional array with all variation prices (including active prices, regular prices and sale prices). 
$prices = $product->get_variation_prices();
$prices_for_display = $product->get_variation_prices( true ); // For display

// The min or max active price.
$min_price = $product->get_variation_price(); // Min active price
$min_price_for_display = $product->get_variation_price('min', true); // Min active price for display
$max_price = $product->get_variation_price('max'); // Max active price
$max_price_for_display = $product->get_variation_price('max', true); // Max active price for display

// The min or max regular price.
$min_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price(); // Min regular price
$min_price_for_display = $product->get_variation_regular_price('min', true); // Min regular price for display
$max_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('max'); // Max regular price
$max_price_for_display = $product->get_variation_regular_price('max', true); // Max regular price for display

// The min or max sale price.
$min_price = $product->get_variation_sale_price(); // Min sale price
$min_price_for_display = $product->get_variation_sale_price('min', true); // Min sale price for display
$max_price = $product->get_variation_sale_price('max'); // Max sale price
$max_price_for_display = $product->get_variation_sale_price('max', true); // Max sale price for display
```

---

Related answers:

[Disable WooCommerce Payment methods if cart item quantity limit is reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029911/disable-woocommerce-payment-methods-if-cart-item-quantity-limit-is-reached/45030396#45030396)

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer with nice explanation but i dont want to match with product category, i just want that if the minimum price is selected just unset the cod gateway

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for that :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'get_min_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'get_min_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );

function get_min_variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {
    $min_variation_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min');
    return wc_price($min_variation_price);
}
```

Comment: if i want to add the minimum price in another function, is there a way??